# Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null when using Firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am creating a Flutter application that uses Firebase. I keep getting an error when trying to use `Firebase.initializeApp()`.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:myapp/screens/home/home.dart';
import 'package:myapp/screens/landing/landing.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    Future<User> currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser as Future<User>;

    return FutureBuilder<User>(
        future: currentUser,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot){
          if (snapshot.hasData){
            User user = snapshot.data; 
            return HomeScreen();
          }
          return LandingScreen();
        }
    );
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
E/flutter (31443): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
E/flutter (31443): #0      new FirebaseOptions.fromMap (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/firebase_options.dart:78:47)
E/flutter (31443): #1      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeFirebaseAppFromMap (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:44:23)
E/flutter (31443): #2      ListMixin.forEach (dart:collection/list.dart:86:13)
E/flutter (31443): #3      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:34:10)
E/flutter (31443): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31443): #4      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:75:13)
E/flutter (31443): #5      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:25)
E/flutter (31443): #6      main (package:myapp/main.dart:12:18)
E/flutter (31443): #7      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:231:25)
E/flutter (31443): #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter (31443): #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (31443): #10     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
E/flutter (31443): #11     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618:12)
E/flutter (31443): #12     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:223:5)
E/flutter (31443): #13     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
E/flutter (31443): #14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
E/flutter (31443):
```

My `main.dart` line 12 is `Firebase.initializeApp()`

What am I missing?

---

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: myapp

description: Myapp

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4

  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1

  firebase_core: 0.5.3


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

---

**Update**

I have been able to get around the error by entirely changing my structure of `main.dart` like below.  This was taken from a Flutter example:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // Create the initialization Future outside of `build`:
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize FlutterFire:
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'MyApp',
            home: LandingScreen(),
          );
        }

        // Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'MyApp',
            home: LandingScreen(),
          );
        }

        // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'MyApp',
          home: LandingScreen(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

While this does seem to work, I would still love to know why the other structure was not working, when it seems that the other structure is what is recommended in most docs.

Comment: `currentUser` returns a value of type `User`, you need to use `Future`

Comment: @PeterHaddad Where would I use `Future`?

Comment: you dont need to use `Future`*

Comment: @PeterHaddad It seems I'm still getting the same error as above

Comment: is it the same with any different widget other than MyApp ?

Comment: make sure that you have the latest version of firebase auth, core in your pubspec.yaml.

Comment: also, you can try  to invalidate cashes/restart your android studio

Comment: @Shalabyer I've tried closing and restarting Android Studio, and removed MyApp and tried with the AuthExampleApp from this example: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/example

All seem to produce the same error.  How do I invalidate the caches?

Comment: Firebase Core is now required since the most recent update to the SDKs.  Make sure to add it to pubspec.ysml as @Shalabyer said.

Comment: run `flutter clean` do `File>Invalidate and restart`, make sure firebase libraries are upto date in gradle file, and dont forget to add correct google services json and make sure it isn't modified, check whether `projectID` exists in the json (just to be sure)

Comment: I think that you might want a fresh start, I mean create a new project and follow the steps of creating a new firebase project carefully.

Comment: Same issue here - but for me its probably related to that we use flutter as a module within our android app which is also using firebase. Still searching for a solution. All above mentioned proposals did not worked for me

Comment: @LuckyMalaka I was able to restructure and get it to work, but I'm still pretty confused about why the other way throws an error.  The other way seems to be the normal structure for using Firebase in a flutter app